# Assetic Global Load for JavaScript Files Affects CSS

Tags: symfony, assetic

I porting my web site to the Symfony framework. I'm using Assetic for my assets. After I got the bugs out, I wanted consolidate the code. When I did, I ran into a problem apparently unrelated to what I was changing. This is the working code:

```
{% stylesheets 'bundles/zetchoamcolan/css/screen.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% stylesheets 'bundles/zetchoamcolan/css/SpryTooltip.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
{% javascripts 'bundles/zetchoamcolan/js/modernizr-custom.80696.js'
               'bundles/zetchoamcolan/js/SpryTooltip.js' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

I wanted to load the javascript without specifying the files so I changed the last bit of code to:

```
{% javascripts 'bundles/zetchoamcolan/js/*' %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

When I do that, I loose a background image specified in the css file. The rest of the css formatting seems to be functioning. The two JavaScript files mentioned are the only files in the js directory. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Update:** The missing image is parchment.gif. I checked images directory under both scenarios. The file doesn't appear when I use '/*' above. Instead, a file called parchment_border.png does. I use this file elsewhere in my css. I'm using the Safari Inspect Element to determine this.

**Update 2:** It was an user error. I entered "modernizr-custom.80696" when it should have been "modernizr.custom.80696". I double checked the spelling, but not the punctuation. When modernizr is specified correctly, it invokes some CSS that sets the background image to none. I don't know why I have that in there.

Comment: When you say you loose the background image, you mean the background properties is not here anymore or it looks like it hasn't been rewritten by the filter?

Comment: Good question. I just meant I didn't see it. When I added back in the problem code the url for the missing image in css was: "background-image: url(../images/parchment.gif);". It is unchanged from the working version. In addition, there is another background image declared in the same manner that appears in both scenarios.

Comment: I have seen your edit: the image file changes when you use the `/*` code? Where is this image located??

Comment: In AmColAnBundle/Resources/public/images. I imagine the directory I'm seeing in the browser inspect window is a generated one.

Comment: Can you [dump the assetics](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment) and/or cleared the cache to try?

Comment: I think it's the modernizr.js that's causing the problem. I tried a bunch of different combinations. In some cases the modernizr file was shown in red and had no contents in the browser. Thinking it might be the version I had, I downed loaded a new one. The display problem is still there, but now I can get it to load consistently. I'm porting everything from a straight PHP version (i.e., no framework). That site doesn't have this problem. I'm going to look into the what CSS is produced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the image paths in your CSS. The Assetic bundle will compress/join the specified files and put the output in the css/ or js/ folder.

In your css, your image paths need to be changed from `../images/image.jpg` to `/bundles/yourbundle/images/image.jpg`

Comment: This is wrong. He is using the [`cssrewrite` filter](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#fixing-css-paths-with-the-cssrewrite-filter) so no need to use absolute path.